# php replace a pattern

Tags: php

Suppose in a file there is a pattern as 
          `sumthing.c:` and
           `asdfg.c:`   and many more.. with *.c: pattern

How to replace this with the text `yourinput` and save the file using php

The pattern is  `*.c`

thanks..

Comment: Doesn't make any sense, what are you trying to replace with "yourinput"? You can't replace the filenames of multiple files.

Answer (score 3):

You can read the contents of the file into a `PHP` `string` using `file_get_contents`, do the `*.c` to `yourinput` replacement in the string and write it back to the file using `file_put_contents`:

```
$filename = '...'; // name of your input file.
$file = file_get_contents($filename) or die();
$replacement = '...'; // the yourinput thing you mention in the quesion
$file = preg_replace('/\b\w+\.c:/',$replacement,$file);
file_put_contents($file,$filename) or die();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP's str_replace or str_replace ( in case its a regex pattern). CHeck the syntax of these two functions and replace the *.c with your input.

*.c pattern should be something like /*?(.c)$/

Comment: wouldn't it be `/\.c$/` ? (I've never see a ? at the start of a regex before: what's it do?)

Answer (score 0):

First open file and get it's content:

```
$content = file_get_contents($path_to_file);
```

Than modify the content:

```
$content = preg_replace('/.*\.c/', 'yourinput');
```

Finally save the result back to the file.

```
file_put_contents($path_to_file, $content);
```

**Note:** You may consider changing the regexp because this way it match the `'.c'` string and everything before it. Maybe `'/[a-zA-Z]*\.c/'` is what you want.

Comment: `/^.*\.c$/` is how you'd match the whole line - don't forget the `$` at the end there, otherwise any file with ".c" in it (eg: myfile.cab, myfile.current.txt) will be matched.